# Upgrading ReportViewer from v8 to v9 (VS2005 to VS2009)

Tags: reportviewer

I've got an ASP.NET v2 application which I've just upgraded to ASP.NET v3.5, moving from VS2005 to VS2008 at the same time. The application uses the Microsoft ReportViewer. A new version of the ReportViewer is included with VS2008 (v9.0.0.0) but the upgrade wizard doesn't automatically update the reports from v8 to v9.

I can change the references manually but wondered if there was anything else to do to upgrade?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports (rdl/rdlc files) don't need to be updated, they will work fine.